# JTextField to Properties file

Tags: java, properties, append, jtextfield, fileinputstream

I am trying to append the input in a Jtextfield into a test properties config file I have setup. However, I am receive the NullPointerException every time I try to append the text. I've read that Properties API doesn't allow adding/remove/editing so I also tried BufferedWriter but it doesn't work either. If anyone know a way to do this I would be very grateful.

Appending text via JButton:

```
 if (userField.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                lblNullUser.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                lblNullUser.setVisible(false);
            }

            if(!chckbxRememberUser.isSelected()) {
                //To do: go to Lynx
            } else {
                String user = userField.getText();
                c.prop.setProperty("user", user); //null on this line; problem might be the key but not sure how to fix

                try {

                    c.prop.store(c.outputSteam, null);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Configuration class:

```
public String Config() throws IOException{
    String result = "";
    prop = new Properties();
    propFileName = "config.properties";

    inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
    outputSteam = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
    prop.load(inputStream);
    if (inputStream == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Config file '" + propFileName + "' not found.");
    }

    //Date time = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show the codes where `c.prop` come from.

Answer (score 0):

`Hashtable` which is parent class of `Properties` throws `NullPointerException`  if the key or value is null.

Make sure that the both the key and the value are not `null`. In your case either the `value` is null or the `properties` object itself is null. 
Add a check something like this to validate and update the property.

```
String user = userField.getText();
if (user != null && c.prop != null) {
  c.prop.setProperty("user", user);
} else {
  // Some params are null - log and verify
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a NullPointer exception I suggest to check the inputStream for null before using it to load properties.

```
if (inputStream == null) {
  throw new FileNotFoundException("Config file '" + propFileName + "' not found.");
}
prop.load(inputStream);
```

However, your whole code contains much more potential for trouble:

- Is Config() meant to be a constructor? It isn't because it returns a String. It makes no sense to initialize instance variables in such a method that way.
- You're not closing inputStream and outputStream anywhere.
- Opening outputStream in advance (before needing it) is a bad idea.
- Accessing fields of another class directly (without getter) is bad style.
- ...